# SQL join with three tables, one table returns unknown number of results, dont want duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

OK, so I'm using node and MySQL, having issues with a query.

I have three tables, we'll call them T1, T2, and T3. T1 has a primary key, we'll call it T1.id. T3 also has a primary key, T3.id.

T2 has a primary key, T2.id, and foreign keys which point to T1.id (FK1) and T3.id (FK3). So now let's look at a sample data set:

```
T1_____     T2________              T3_____
id -name    | id -FK1 -FK3          | id  -name
1  johnny   | 1  .... 1 ....  1  .. |  1  ..  MN
2  william  | 2 ....  1 ....  2  .. |  2  ..  FL
3  joseph   | 3  .... 1 ....  3  .. |  3  ..  CA
4  bobbie   | 4 ....  2 ....  2  
------------| 5 ....  2  .... 3
------------| 6 ....  3 ....  1
------------| 7 ....  3  .... 2
------------| 8  .... 3  .... 3
```

I want a query that will return columns from T1, and then join (unknown number of) columns of T2 for each match, and then for each T2 match, join columns from T3 for its corresponding match.

So, for example, the first row would be:

```
T1.name  T2.1.id T2.1.T3.name T2.2.id T2.2.T3.name T2.3.id T2.3.T3.name
johnny   1       MN           2       FL           3       CA
```

*** Sorry for the formatting. Is this doable, or do I need to use a non-relational DB like Mongo or Couchbase?

Comment: "unknown number of columns of T2"?  You have specified exactly three columns in T2.  What is unknown?

Comment: Well you will see that for each entry in T1, there are a different amount of matches in T2. Hypothetically it could range from 1 to 10 for each person in T1, this is just a small sample. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified solution: Merge all the data from T3 table into one column in the result set.

```
SELECT      t1.name,
            GROUP_CONCAT(t3.id,' ',t3.name SEPARATOR ', ') as data
    FROM    t1
    JOIN    t2
        ON  t2.fk1 = t1.id
    JOIN    t3
        ON  t3.id = t2.fk2
GROUP BY    t1.id;
```

It would produce result

```
T1.name         | data
johnny          | 1 MN, 2 FL, 3 CA
```

with configurable delimiters.

Extended solution: Prepare dynamic query taking advantage of pivoting:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN ind=', @i := @i+1, ' THEN x.t3id ELSE NULL END) AS col', @i, 'id,MAX(CASE WHEN ind=', @i, ' THEN x.name ELSE NULL END) AS col', @i, 'name') 
FROM    t2,
        (SELECT @i := 0) init
WHERE   t2.fk1 = (
    SELECT      fk1
        FROM    (
            SELECT      t2.fk1, 
                        COUNT(t2.fk2) as cnt
                FROM    t2
            GROUP BY    t2.fk1
            ORDER BY    cnt DESC
                LIMIT   1
            ) tmp
        ) 
INTO @sql;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT x.t1name,', @sql, ' FROM ( SELECT @i := IF(@id = tmp.id, @i+1, 1) as ind, @id := tmp.id as id, tmp.t1name, tmp.t3id, tmp.name FROM (SELECT t1.id, t1.name as t1name, t3.id as t3id, t3.name FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t2.fk1 = t1.id JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.fk2,(SELECT @i := 1, @id := 0) init ORDER BY t1.id) tmp) x GROUP BY x.id');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This approach will create and execute query looking like:

```
SELECT      x.t1name,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ind = 1 THEN x.t3id ELSE NULL END) AS col1id,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ind = 1 THEN x.name ELSE NULL END) AS col1name,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ind = 2 THEN x.t3id ELSE NULL END) AS col2id,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ind = 2 THEN x.name ELSE NULL END) AS col2name,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ind = 3 THEN x.t3id ELSE NULL END) AS col3id,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ind = 3 THEN x.name ELSE NULL END) AS col3name
    FROM    (
        SELECT      @i := IF(@id = tmp.id, @i+1, 1) as ind,
                    @id := tmp.id as id,
                    tmp.t1name,
                    tmp.t3id,
                    tmp.name
            FROM    (
                SELECT      t1.id,
                            t1.name as t1name,
                            t3.id as t3id,
                            t3.name
                    FROM    t1
                    JOIN    t2
                        ON  t2.fk1 = t1.id
                    JOIN    t3
                        ON  t3.id = t2.fk2,
                            (SELECT @i := 1, @id := 0) init
                ORDER BY    t1.id
            ) tmp
        ) x
GROUP BY    x.id;
```

Which gives the following result:

```
 t1name  | col1id | col1name | col2id | col2name | col3id | col3name 
 johnny  |      1 | MN       |      2 | FL       |      3 | CA       
 william |      2 | FL       |      3 | CA       |   NULL | NULL
```

There is one limitation here however, regarding the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024.

Comment: Yeah I want to avoid using CONCAT if possible. Think of T1 as men (who can have multiple wives). Think of T2 as their wives (who can only have one husband). And then T3 is information about the mothers and fathers of the wives. I want to be able to pull a table of each man, and the information about all of his wives and extended family in each row

Comment: I have added also approach based on pivoting, which will give separate columns in the result

Comment: Awesome! The only issue is that, for example, in your instance there is a maximum number of matches in T2. So it doesn't account for a truly unknown number of matches. But I mean I could just make enough of those rows that it would be highly unlikely for a query to need more, so it' s useable.

Comment: It does! The first SELECT .... INTO @sql, creates the number of columns required based on the select to the t2 table. The query below is just an example made using the exemplary data you specified. You can try it on bigger example and it should work (taking into account the group_concat limitations I wrote about)

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way using `LEFT JOIN` and `group_concat`

```
select 
    T1.name, 
    group_concat(T2.id) as T2Ids,
    group_concat(T3.name) as States
from T1 left join T2 ON T1.id = T2.FK1
        left join T3 ON T3.id = T2.FK3
group by T1.id
```

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` on T3 is going to effectively turn the `LEFT JOIN` on T2 into an `INNER JOIN`, so you might as well make it one explicitly as this can sometimes improve performance.

Comment: The problem is now I'm getting multiple rows for each match in T1, I was hoping for one row for Johnny, that shows the ID's of all the matches for him in T2 and then a state from T3 for each of those matches. If that makes sense?

Comment: Updated the post based on both comments. Pls try if it works as expected.

Comment: Getting close! Is there any way to make new rows instead of concatenating the T2 and T3 results into strings?

Comment: do you want them in separate columns in the same row ?

Comment: Yes, separate columns in the same row. I want to avoid concatenating them into a string unless it's absolutely necessary